# Why does this sql call require a where clause?

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table that looks like

```
ID         Name        amount
1          x             10
2          y             20
3          z             30
```

I want to count the number of IDs and sum the amounts.
I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(table.ID) as NumberOfIds and SUM(table.AMOUNT)
FROM table
```

but I keep getting an error that I'm missing my where statement. Neither of these functions require a where statement by themselves, so why is it asking for one when they are together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `and` to specify multiple desired results, you use commas.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(table.ID) as NumberOfIds, SUM(table.AMOUNT) as SumOfAmounts
FROM table
```